# Getting the property of an object literal in JS from C#

Tags: c#, javascript

I'm currently trying to get the value of a property of an object literal. I have a browser control in my C# program, and I can easily get the value of a *global* variable with the following:

```
...
mshtml.IHTMLDocument domDoc = ((mshtml.IHTMLDocument2)_browser.Document.DomDocument)
object script = domDoc.Script;
object nameOfVariable = script.GetType().InvokeMember("nameOfVariable", BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, script, null);
...
```

If, on the other hand, my variable in the JS is actually a property of an object literal:

```
var NameOfLiteral = {
    var nameOfVariable: false // EDIT: no var as jbabey pointed out
};
```

I can use the previous code to get the Com object containing the literal, but I have absolutely no clue how to inspect it to get the property. Is there any good example somewhere showing how to do what I want to do?

Comment: `nameOfVariable` is not a variable (your example code is erroneous). It is a **property** of `NameOfLiteral`.

Comment: I'll try to reformulate the question, but then how to you get a property of an object literal from C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax is not valid javascript, it should be:

```
var NameOfLiteral = {
    nameOfVariable: false // no "var" on object properties
};
```

Then, you should be able to access that property from your C# like so:

```
object nameOfVariable = script.GetType().InvokeMember("NameOfLiteral.nameOfVariable" ...);
```

Comment: I can actually get the value if I do it in two steps. First getting the literal, and then the property, using InvokeMember twice. Otherwise I'm getting an Unknown Name exception.